Rocky Linux Emergency Mode in KVMachine does not start
I have "inherited" a virtual server at German hoster STRATO with Rocky Linux 8, but no root password. I wanted to change this as usual, so in grub I entered
rd.break enforcing=0
Enter rd.break enforcing=0 into grub and Ctrl+X should start Rocky Linux in emergency mode.
Unfortunately it doesn't start with it, just hangs. Is there a known problem with the KVM or is STRATO blocking something?
STRATO also has a "rescue system" that starts a Debian where I can mount the disks - but I don't know how to change the password from there. A chroot into the shell of root is possible, but a password changed there should be useless for Rocky with SELinux.
Any ideas?
Best regards
Albi
